# Convert a line of text which contains numbers and letters to int

Tags: python, mysql

I am working on a program that reads an RFID card, and then pulls information about that card from a database. I am using Python with MySQL for this but in order for it to work I need to convert a string, e.g. `"2345d566k"`, to an int. I don't need the letters to be in there, just the numbers.

when I do the following:

```
test = "2345d566k"
test2 = int(test)
```

it returns: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2345d566k'`

How could I convert this string to an int?

Comment: Uh..... What int are you looking for?

Comment: To expand on the above, what do you expect the output to be for an input of "2345d566k"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use regex for this

```
import re

"".join(re.findall('\d', "ab23cd56e3f"))
```

It will parse all numeric digit from the given string, If you will put `\D` in place of `\d` it will result all alphabets.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to ignore characters other than digits, a simple solution would be

```
test = "ab23cd56e3f"
test2 = int(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), test))
#test2 is now 23563
```

`filter()` applies the `isdigit()` function to every character of the string, keeping only those that are digits. Then you can safely call `int()` to convert the result to an integer.

As pointed out in the comments, this will only work if every line of text you want to convert contains at least 1 digit.

Comment: Which will work fine right up until you get either a card that only has non-numeric characters, or two cards that only differ in non-numeric characters.

Comment: @Ignacio: I doubt the OP wants to use this as a means of distinguishing between RFID cards. However, you are right about the non-numeric part.

Comment: "and then pulls information about that card from a database" I'd say that counts as "distinguishing".

Comment: You might be right, but it wouldn't make sense to use this int as a means of querying the database, since the OP could just use the alphanumeric value.

Comment: The OP wasn't clear; I think this was the best useful answer given the lack of info.